# Need help to make sense of NDKHelper

Tags: c++, objective-c

[Here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/How_to_work_on_iOS_-_C++Objective-C) is the tutorial on how to call back and forth between c++ to object-c .

But isn't object-c compatible with c++ in the first place?

We can put c++ and object-c together directly, why the hard way around?

Comment: Just use the `objective-c++` dialect for which no bridge is needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C has an Objective-C++ bridge, that allows you to use C++ code within the context of an Objective-C runtime. However, the vice versa does not exist, if you're building a C++ object you cannot call into the Objective-C runtime so NDKHelper sets up a communication channel to allow it.

Comment: About the obj-c to c++ direction, in the tut,why there's a IOSNDKHelper which is used to pass message from obj-c to c++ if obj-c can call c++ directly?

Comment: There's some fiddly bits going on, you can call C++ code but not treat it as an Objective-C object which means you can't necessarily use it for messaging in the Objective-C world.

Comment: What about some more detail about the fiddly bits?

Comment: There's a good article here: http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++ about mixing the two. If I remember rightly there's a more in-depth article on the Apple developer resources as well.

Comment: Thank you for the effort you spent into answering my Q:)